# Get strings from QRegex pattern (return as Stringlist / arrays)

Tags: qt4, qregexp

Example:

```
QFile controller_selected_file(loaded_file);

if (controller_selected_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    // grab a data
    QTextStream in(&controller_selected_file);

    // read all
    QString read_data = in.readAll();

    // Regex for match function "public function something()"
    QRegExp reg("(static|public|final)(.*)function(.*)[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]", Qt::CaseInsensitive);

    // Read by regex and file
    reg.indexIn(read_data);

    QStringList data_render = reg.capturedTexts();

    qDebug() << data_render;

    qDebug() << data_render[0];
    qDebug() << data_render[1];
    qDebug() << data_render[3];

    // ...
}
```

I want grab in a file all where appears `public function somefunction()` and another `public function something($a,$b = "example")` where appears in file, but I only receives full of file string or receive only `public` on first array.

So I want grab all data where appears as arrays:

`public function somefunction()`.

So in simple, parse all function names in file.

Full function of regex in QRegexp expression:

```
(static|public|final)(.*)function(.*)[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]
```

Edit: I want grab all appears in strings on PHP file. Problems appears when you receive all strings in file instead strings defined with regular expression.

Thank you for respect!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question right, I think you need to modify the regex as `QRegExp reg( "((static|public|final).*function.*\([\\w\\s,]*\))" );`

With the above RegExp, you can match something like `static function  newFunc( int gen_x, float A_b_c )`

```
QFile controller_selected_file(loaded_file);

if (controller_selected_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    // grab a data
    QTextStream in(&controller_selected_file);

    // read all
    QString read_data = in.readAll();

    // Regex for match function "public function something()"
    QRegExp reg( "((static|public|final).*function.*\([\\w\\s,]*\))" );

    // Read by regex and file
    qDebug() << reg.indexIn( read_data );
    qDebug() << reg.cap( 1 );
    // ...
}
```

Say `read_data` contains the following text

```
"This is some text: static function newFunc( int generic, float special )
And it also contains some other text, but that is not important"
```

Then the output will be

```
19
"static function newFunc( int generic, float special )"
```

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: `warning: unknown escape sequence: '\)' [enabled by default]` on `QRegExp reg("((static|public|final).*function.*\([\\w\\s,]*\))");`

Comment: Change `\(` and `\)` to `\\(` and `\\)`

Comment: Try add another function in file, it will grab all, not grab only captured strings :(